# Duplicate entry mysql when inserting UUID_SHORT for primary key

Tags: mysql, uuid

I got which I do not understand so far, I got a duplicate entry error message with I'm trying to insert a UUID_SHORT for my primary index.

The id column is an integer 18, and the UUID_SHORT is generated using a BEFORE_INSERT trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TR_Documents_BI` BEFORE INSERT ON `documents`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.id = UUID_SHORT()
```

The error is

```
 Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I read on stackoverflow that I should try storing my data with a BigInt, but the result is not so convincing neither as the first UUID_SHORT generated gives :

```
95161384827879440
```

nd the next one like auto-increment are

```
95161384827879440 + 1
```

I don't get why I cannot have a UUID_SHORT as my primary index.

However, the problem doensn't exist if I generate a UUID();

Someone could help please ?

**Edit :** Impossible to store UUID_SHORT as Integer, got it! But when I use BigInt(18), I got the following entry generated: 
95161384827879440,
95161384827879441, 
95161384827879442, 
95161384827879443, 
95161384827879444

with the following error message :

```
Warning: #1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1
```

So it's still not a generated UUID_SHORT() stored in my column :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `BIGINT`. An INT(18) is still 32bit and can't hold 18 decicmal digits.

As to the uniqueness of UUID_SHORT you should check the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short).

Comment: Thanks for answering @Vatev but when I use BigInt(18), I got the following entry generated:
95161384827879440, 95161384827879441, 95161384827879442, 95161384827879443, 95161384827879444


with the following error message :

    `Warning: #1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1`

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Vatev use bigint
and then as a safety net use [ON DUPLICATE .... KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

That should take care of your problem :)